# Kernel error during upgrade due to "/etc/default/grub: Syntax error: newline unexpected"

Tags: upgrade, apt, kernel

Summary: linux-image-3.5.0-2-generic upgrade to linux-image-3.5.0-3-generic

The default Ubuntu 12.04 update is generating the following error for weeks (the link below).

*Obs.: I'm using default update of Ubuntu 12.04 ie, **apt-get** update.*

log error: https://gist.github.com/3036775

Overall he is trying to do the following: upgrade the "linux-image-3.5.0-2-generic upgrade to linux-image-3.5.0-3-generic" and the error always, always.

What to do?

Comment: Have you edited /etc/default/grub?  It seems like there is a syntax error in this file, such as a missing quotation mark.  If a line has an open quote (either single or double), but no closing quote before the end of the line, the it will complain about the newline (ie, linebreak) inside the quotes.

Comment: Oh god my friend. You complete CORRECTLY. I will fix the problem in line 26 (just comment - #), and works now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Cool.  This type of problem is actually fairly common in many different programming languages.  Which is why I knew what it probably would be.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my friend review, managed to solve the problem:

> Have you edited /etc/default/grub? It seems like there is a syntax
>   error in this file, such as a missing quotation mark. If a line has an
>   open quote (either single or double), but no closing quote before the
>   end of the line, the it will complain about the newline (ie,
>   linebreak) inside the quotes. – Marty Fried Jul 4 at 3:19

The error was in line 26, then sufficed comment (#) the line and ready.